# Crystal Reports Parameter Input dialog box changing the date format

Tags: date, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

When I generate a report that expects two date parameters, I first see the dialog box titled 'Enter Values' and the dialog box contains two text boxes with its own date picker widget. However, once I pick a date and click 'OK', the date is formatted as 'dd/MM/yyyy'. Does anyone know if it is possible to configure the report in a way so that the date format matches Windows system locale short date format? Instead of just defaulting to dd/MM/yyyy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The date format for the parameter can't be changed, at least as far as I know. If you want the date displayed in a different format, you can always create a formula:

```
"From : " & ToText(Minimum({?date}), "M-d-yy") & 
" To :" & ToText(Maximum({?date}), "M-d-yy")
```

Or you can go into the File menu, click on Options and under the Fields tab, there is a button for Date. Click on that and you can choose the format under the Date tab. This is for CR 2008, so it may be slightly different for CR XI.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That's what I assumed, that it was a Crystal Reports limitation. I checked the default date format by going File > Options... > Fields Tab > Date button > Date tab and saw that System Default Short Format was selected which reflects my windows locale system short date format.

Comment: I found two more links that also say that we cannot change the date format for the parameter of the date picker control: http://scn.sap.com/message/6647542 and http://scn.sap.com/thread/1615310

Answer (score 0):

If You are trying to filter in your SQL on date range field then you can add castings on dates. Like

```
    datarangeField between cast({?Start Date} as date format 'm-d-yy')
                         AND cast({?End Date} as date format 'm-d-yy')
```

Also, you are required to add these (Start Date and End Date) in your SQL Parameters during Adding the query.

For display you can use formulas and format field options.